# how to make looping for select syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

i have table called order_star_member, this table contain **users_id** as buyer, **createdAt** is the date when the buyer doing transaction, and **total_price_star_member** is the amount of each transaction of each buyer, i want to select buyer who has become star member (doing transaction in a month within >= 600000) with this syntax

```
select count(*) from (select users_id, sum(total_price_star_member) from order_star_member where createdAt >= '2020-01-01' and createdAt < '2020-02-01' group by users_id having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000) inner_query;
```

how to make looping on this case, so when it becomes february, the data count itself the buyer who become star member (transaction >= 600.000) and it automatically put in based on the buyer doing transaction from

example:
anto doing transaction in january 600000, and february 750000, anita doing transaction on february 600000 and january 450000, doni doing his first transaction on february with total 650000

so when i run this loop, it become on february 1 star member from january, and 3 star member on february

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this aproach:

```
select
    count(*)
from
    (
    select
        users_id,
        sum(total_price_star_member)
    from
        order_star_member
    where
        createdAt >= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()),
        INTERVAL 1 DAY),
        INTERVAL - 1 MONTH)
        and createdAt <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
    group by
        users_id
    having
        sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000) inner_query;
```

this should help to give you actual month total. Using CURDATE() you find the first day and last day of the month and use them.

Comment: im okay with my query, i just need the looping so if i put in on my website it’s just update automatically with the count of buyer when new data has come on my database

Comment: maybe with store procedure or something

Comment: I am not sure I understand ? you want for this month 600K 3 starts, for last month 600K 1 star ? it's possible to make a union with this month , last month and add the stars ?

Comment: basically i need a looping so the result was mysql can count itself how much starmember (a buyer who spent more than 600k in a month) in february, so if i want to display the february statistic, it appear with arrangment (the buyer who also starmember in january, the buyer who only starmember in february).

Comment: and for march statistic, the buyer who also starmember on january, and then starmember who also starmember on february, and the new buyer on march, and so does april. so i need looping for this case

Comment: the best would be , if last month has stable data , not changing, to save the statement in a cache table and this for every older month. An end of month procedure would do this

Comment: can you more specifically tell me what’s should i do?

Comment: give me 3 different examples and I will try to understand what you need

Comment: ok so if i want to begin the data on 2020, which means there's january untill december 2020, each month are containing amount of buyer who doing first transaction in every month before, example:
1. Januari (containing all of buyer from only january 2020 (because it started in january 2020))
2. February (containing the buyer who come from january, and then containing the buyer who come in february)
3. March (from january, from february, and then from march)
4. April (from january, from february, amount buyer from march, and amount buyer who comes from april itself)

Comment: or you can look at here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810879/how-to-create-procedure-for-data-buyer-mysql